# Show that {△} is functionally complete.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have seen proofs of whether a set of connectives is functionally complete, but never when it is defined by a truth table. I can't quite figure out how to show that {△} is functionally complete if the propositional connective is defined by a truth table.

Here is an image of the truth table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the problem to one you already know how to solve: identify which operation $\Delta$ is in your favorite method of describing them, and then use the method you already know (or reference facts you already know) to see that its functionally complete.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia describes [functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) as follows:

> In logic, a functionally complete set of logical connectives or Boolean operators is one which can be used to express all possible truth tables by combining members of the set into a Boolean expression. A well-known complete set of connectives is { AND, NOT }, consisting of binary conjunction and negation. Each of the singleton sets { NAND } and { NOR } is functionally complete.

To show that the singleton set {△} is functionally complete we need only show that the truth table of the only member of the set is the same as either NAND or NOR.

Here is [Wikipedia's truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Truth_table) for NOR:

[image]

Here is the truth table the OP presented for △:

[image]

Note that the only time either of these truth tables show T (or 1) for the connective is when both of the two propositions being connected are false (F or 0). Therefore △ is the same connective as NOR and since NOR is functionally complete so is △.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, August 23). Functional completeness. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 21:08, August 28, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Functional_completeness&oldid=912152343

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, February 10). Logical NOR. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 21:08, August 28, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Logical_NOR&oldid=882635819